# How to establish foreign key relationship with a non entity table in the database using Spring data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

My spring boot project uses an existing database, I have a new model entity/table in my project that must have a foreign key constraint with an existing table in the database.

I've tried to find solution online but all the answers are for the case where both the tables are present as entities in that project and using some @ManyToOne, @OneToMany annotations.

I can't define those annotations because I don't have the reference table as an entity or model in my project.

Let's say I have class like:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;
    private long departmentId;
```

I want to put a foreign key contraint on the `departmentId` column to reference to `id` column of the existing `department` table that isn't defined as a model or entity in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just do it as normal 
example

```
@Column(name = "department_id")
private Department departmentId;
```

You can later access it `Department.departmentId`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I need to have a `department` entity class with the schema of the department table?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="(column name of current entity)", referencedColumnName="(column name in target entity)")
private Department departmentId;
```

you can skip the referencedColumnName if the column name is same in both the entities

Comment: And yes you need the entity of the target table or else you can't map the whole entity. Another work around is using @Formula